# Getting error while including JavaScript files using Django and Python

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am getting some error while including JavaScript files in templates using Django.

Error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag on line 6: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 6: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in invalid_block_tag, line 571
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.4
```

settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

""" Internationalization """

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


""" Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images) """

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
```

urls.py:

```
"""Neuclear plant URL Configuration"""
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('plant.urls')),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

base.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
{ % load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Nuclear Reactor</h1>
      {% if count > 0  %}
      <b>Hi, {{ user.username }}</b>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
        <a href="{% url 'view_reactor' %}">View Reactor status</a>
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> / <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>
      {% endif %}
      <hr>
    </header>
    <main>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above template file i am getting the error. Here I need to include the js file in this template. I have also `static/js/` folder inside my project directory.

Comment: try putting load static on the top of your file

Comment: `{ % load static %}` there's a space between `{` and `%`

Comment: @dirkgroten: thanks as per you it worked.

Comment: @marni gave the correct answer, pls mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Include `{% load static %}` on the top of your template

Comment: I put it before `<!DOCTYPE html>` also but same error.

Comment: Try it: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/jquery.js` if you will get js - all with settings are ok. Can you paste here the code where you make loading?

Comment: it's `{%` not `{ %`

Answer (score -1):

Add `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()` in urls.py